# LPF design with pole/zero placement at rejection at specified freq

Tags: matlab, filter-design, poles-zeros

I am about to design a low-pass filter with a zero/pole placement method in such a way that rejected frequencies are placed at $500\,\text{Hz}$ and their multiples.

Are there any simple instructions to do it Matlab?

Expected freq. response fo LPF with rejection exact freqs ...

[image]

Comment: "600Hz and their multiples" would imply a comb filter. However, you want to design a "low pass". Which one is it ? Do you care what happens at 900Hz or only what happens at 600Hz and 1200 Hz ?

Comment: just care on 600Hz, 1200Hz

Comment: so, since you say "low pass filter"; a low pass filter that cut offs at say 1250 Hz, and lets throug **everything** below?

Comment: I tried such filters with active power filters but, it turns out, they're not very effective, because the frequencies I wanted rejected were not fixed (jitter, noise, you name it). So, as soon as the harmonics would shift, they were very poorly rejected. I tried doubling the zeroes, having two, closely spaced ones, but that only added delay. The filter, itself, can be built from zeroes and you'll get a Bartlett window of sorts (but not quite). A PLL/locked-in filter, or an adaptive moving average might be better. What you want will only work if those frequencies do not vary, at all.

Comment: That sure looks like a sinc function.  A zero at every integer multiple of 500 Hz except for the zeroth multiple (DC).  The impulse response for a sinc function in the frequency domain is a rectangular function in the time domain, which is the same as a moving average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency response you provide is that of a **moving average filter** (sometimes referred to as a *boxcar* filter). I'm assuming from your graph that your sampling frequency is $f_s = 5000\,\text{Hz}$

---

**EDIT: Ideal analog box-car filter**

The ideal boxcar filter can be expressed in the Laplace domain by combining two opposing unit step (Heaviside) functions into the expression:
$$H_{ideal}(s) = \frac{1}{T}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{e^{-sT}}{s}\right) = \frac{1}{sT}\left(1-e^{sT}\right)$$
To get the frequency response, set $s = j\omega = j2\pi f$:

```
Fs = 5000;
freqVec = (0:Fs/2);
s = 1j*2*pi*freqVec;
T = 1/500;
H = 1./(s*T) .* (1 - exp(-s*T));
plot(10*log10(abs(H)));
```

[image]

---

This filter can be digitally implemented as a FIR filter of length $N = f_s / f_{0}$, where $f_{0}$ is the first frequency you want to notch.

Your sampling frequency is $f_s = 5000\,\text{Hz}$, which gives $N = 5000/500 = 10$.

```
% Matlab

fs = 5000;
N = fs/500;
b = ones(1,N)*1/N; % boxcar filter coefficients

figure(1)
zplane(b,1); % pole zero plot
figure(2)
freqz(b,1,fs,fs); % frequency response
```

**Caveats**

1. This only works if $f_s/f_0$ is an integer. If not, this [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/12743/63763) can guide you.
2. As @aconcernedcitizen mentioned, if you're worried about the frequencies moving around your intended nulls, then this isn't an optimal approach.

---

**EDIT: Continuous-time representation**

Per the OP's request, here are the steps to convert this digital filter to a continuous representation, using [tf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html) and [d2c](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/lti.d2c.html):

```
Ts = 1/5000; % sample time, i.e. inverse of sampling frequency
Hd = tf(b,1,Ts); % Discrete transfer function 
%Hc = d2c(Hd); % Continuous transfer function (error)
Hc = d2c(Hd,'tustin');
```

**Caveat**: this will not give you the same response as the digital or ideal versions. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429595/analog-circuit-for-moving-mean-moving-average/429655#429655)

---

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm gonna try how it works and check it if I get it :)

Comment: Is this approach you showed applicable in s-domain (continues time) or should I use zp2tf(), d2c() matlab function to get filter params in s-domain? How it basically works in s-domain? Thank you.

Comment: It is applicable to the s domain yes. The filter parameters are just the filter coefficients, which are the coefficients in `b`.

Comment: Does it mean 'b' is the same for the s and the z domain? So I am looking for the equivalent of 'zplane' for s-domain ...

Comment: w = logspace(-1,1)
h = freqs(b,1,w)
mag = abs(h)
loglog(w,mag) - it seems no working ...

Comment: @user3428154 Edited my answer ;)

Comment: Hc = d2c(Hd);
Error using DynamicSystem/d2c
The "zoh", "foh", and "impulse" methods cannot be used for improper (non-causal) models.

Comment: This works: Hc = d2c(Hd,'tustin'); h = bodeplot(Hc); setoptions(h,'FreqUnits','Hz','PhaseVisible','off');

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the *z-domain* I am getting the exact frequency response

[image]

I have used the recommended approach to convert from *z-domain* to *s-domain* but I encountered some problems such as

```
Hc = d2c(Hd); Error using DynamicSystem/d2c 
              The "zoh", "foh", and "impulse" methods cannot be used for improper (non-causal) models.
```

So I specified the conversion method.

```
>> d2c(Hd,'tustin')
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I am not getting the exact frequency response that I require:

[image]

If I try to use the discretization method '*Zero-Pole Matching Equivalents*' to have a good matching in the frequency domain between the continuous- and discrete-time models then it does not work.

[image]

How to have a good matching of frequency response between *z-domain* and *s-domain* or how exactly to design the filter for *s-domain* and *z-domain* with no conversion to match the required frequency response?

Note: (my m-code for the reference)

```
% Matlab

fs = 5000;
N = fs/500;
b = ones(1,N)*1/N; % boxcar filter coefficients

figure(1)
zplane(b,1); % pole zero plot
figure(2)
freqz(b,1,fs,fs); % frequency response

Ts = 1/5000; % sample time, i.e. inverse of sampling frequency
Hd = tf(b,1,Ts); % Discrete transfer function 
Hc = d2c(Hd,'Tustin'); % Continuous transfer function

plotoptions = bodeoptions;
plotoptions.Grid = 'on';
plotoptions.FreqScale = 'linear';
plotoptions.Title.String = 'Filter with exact freq. response';
plotoptions.FreqUnits = 'Hz';
plotoptions.PhaseVisible = 'off';
plotoptions.XLim = {[1 3000]};
bodeplot(Hc,plotoptions)
```

[image]

by using

```
Fs = 5000;
freqVec = (0:Fs/2);
s = 1j*2*pi*freqVec;
T = 1/500;
H = 1./(s*T) .* (1 - exp(-s*T));
plot(10*log10(abs(H)));
```

Comment: You can't design any arbitrary digital filter and convert them to analog. At best you'll get a close approximation. At worst it's impossible. Please see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/429655) for example.

Comment: OK. So how do I design *s-domain* filter with the required freq. response - I do not need conversion.

Comment: Edited my answer with the ideal s-domain frequency response formula. Not sure what you can do with that though. You won't be able to actually implement an analog filter with this frequency response. You can, however, implement the digital version easily (with the original answer).

Comment: GREAT! Thank you!

Comment: I just wonder if there is some feature that allow execution directly and copy to MATLAB mobile MATLAB online This can be nice to check code snippet

Comment: I'd like to use it in continuous time Simulink simulation as "transfer function" tf() with [num, den] - I'm struggling to extract num, den .. " [num,den] = tfdata(H); " or "[num den] = tf(H, 'v')" - how should I use it correctly within SImulink simulation **H(s) = 1./(s*T) .* (1 - exp(-s*T));