# removing spikes from spectrum

Tags: fft, filters, frequency-spectrum, noise

I am working on 50 samples obtained from time domain signal by FFT. It appears at certain frequencies which are -- according to our experimentalist -- due to some issues with their oscilloscope. What is the best way to remove these?
They seem to appear at fixed frequencies only but they are not present in all samples to the same degree.
[image]

Comment: At which frequency do these spikes first occur? Your plots starts at 3 gHz.

Comment: @Jdip changed the picture.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't make out where the first spike happens. So, what is the frequency at which the first spike occurs?

Comment: @jdip It is at 250 MHz

Comment: Ok, and I'm guessing it's also at 500, 750, 1000, 1250, etc ?

Comment: @jdip yes that is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These spikes look like harmonics of some sort of line noise at $250 \texttt{MHz}$. To get rid of these, what you need is a comb notch filter.

There are a few ways to build one.

1. If the fundamental (your first spike) is an integer divisor of the
   sampling frequency (i.e $f_s/f_0 = \texttt{integer}$), such a filter
   can be built using the following transfer function:

   $$H(z) = g\frac{1-z^{-n}}{1-az^{-n}}$$ with  $$n = \frac{f_s}{f_0}$$

   $$g = \frac{1}{1+\beta}$$ $$a = 2g-1$$ $$\beta =
   \tan\left(\frac{\pi
   n\texttt{BW}}{f_s}\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{\alpha}$$
   $$\alpha = 10^{-A/20}$$ with $\texttt{BW}(\texttt{Hz})$ the width
   of the notch at $-A(\texttt{dB})$.

[image]

Matlab Code:

```matlab
    fs = 20e9;
    fo = 250e6;
    n = fs/fo;
    bw = 2e6;
    A = 3;
    alpha = 10^(-A/20);
    beta = tan(pi*n*bw/(2*fs)) * sqrt(1-alpha^2)/alpha;
    g = 1/(1+beta);
    
    b = [g zeros(1,n-1) -g]; a = [1 zeros(1,n-1) -(2*g-1)];
    
    %filter your signal:
    filtered_signal = filter(b,a,input);
```

---

2. If $f_s/f_0 \neq \texttt{integer}$, or if the spikes aren't actually harmonics, see [this approach][1]

Comment: For some reason the link isn't rendering. Here it is: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/12743/63763

Comment: Thank you very much!